# Osmdroid tries to redraw a deleted polygon during Fragment.onStart()

Tags: android, android-livedata, osmdroid, mutablelivedata

So I've been developing an app where I included a map view from osmdroid, and draw a (new) polygon in there using LiveData whenever a Polygon is saved into my Room Database. Now while cycling back and forth into the fragment with the map, the map tries to "draw" a Polygon that shouldn't be there anymore. This Polygon surprisingly has its private attribute `mOutline == null` and thus throws a `NullPointerException` when the fragment tries to add it to the map. It isn't inside my database, because I cleared in during `Fragment.onViewCreated()`, where I also removed all overlays from the map...:

```
//in onViewCreated of my Fragment:
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    //...

    OverlayManager overlayManager = view_binding.map.getOverlayManager();
    overlayManager.removeAll(overlayManager.overlays());
    view_model.clearPolygon() 
    /* -> now the database is empty (I checked it!) and the 
    * ViewModels.polygon value is set to null using postValue(null)
    * this call also is executed in another thread, because I apparantly am not allowed to
    *access my database on the main thread
    */

    view_model.polygon.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), polygon -> {
        // the null check is here because the Database->LiveData return 
        // null after view_model.clearPolygon()
        if (polygon != null) {
            setPolygon(polygon);
        }
    });

    //...
}

setPolygon(Polygon polygon) {
    polygon.getFillPaint().setColor(Color.parseColor("#1EFFE70E"));
    view_binding.map.getOverlayManager().add(polygon);
    view_binding.map.invalidate();
    IMapController mapController = view_binding.map.getController();
    mapController.setCenter(polygon.getActualPoints().get(0));
    mapController.setZoom(16.0);    
}
```

Now this works up to the point where I use my "back" button to go back into the previous fragment and reenter the fragment with the map, where I again choose a Polygon to draw, write it into the database (which has been cleared before!) and the fragment draws it from LiveData again... **But** during `Fragment.onStart()`, while the database is empty, it first tries to draw this wierd polygon without outline. I could just catch the `NullPointerException` but I think there is some kind of error in my own code and that would be a dirty solution. Any clues?

Edit: forgot to finish a comment in the code section

Answer (score 0):

So right after posting this question (of course -_-) I found a fix which is less dirty: In my ViewModel the `clearPolygon()` method looked like this:

```
clearPolygon() {
    // with callback to post the null value to the private field
    repository.clearPolygon(_polygon::postValue); 
}
```

I changed this to:

```
clearPolygon() {
    _polygon.setValue(null);
    // with callback to post the null value to the private field
    repository.clearPolygon(_polygon::postValue);
}
```

Now the problem is gone and eventually the Repository will be the "single source of truth" again (as soon as the postValue-thingy arrives). I still feel like this isn't the perfect solution, because of the short-time-inconsistency between ViewModel and Repository, so for the moment I'm not gonna mark this answer as accepted, in case anybody comes up with a better solution...